# R-Studio error while trying to create a plot , with " type" and "col" function

Tags: r

The notes in which I am using states to type the following.

```r
plot(x,y,type="1",xlim=c(1000,1500),ylim=c(0,0.009),lwd=2,col="red", ylab="p")
```

The first error comes when I do `type="1"` and then the other is `col="red"` 
Has the function change for type and color.

> Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid plot type '1'

Comment: I'm guessing you want type `l` (the lowercase `L`) instead of the number `1` (one) for line type? (I think `col` should be ok for color.)

Comment: switch 1 to l . That work but the red line didn't come in.

Comment: If you don't mind, please share a sample of your data for x and y to make this reproducible. For example using `dput(head(x))` and same for y. What does show up instead of red line? Are your points within your set limits?

Comment: So the next step was to enter a polygon(c(1100,x,1300),c(0,y,0),col="lightgray",border=NA)    we are doing distribution . the X is x <-seq(,1300,length=600) and Y is y <- dunif(x,min=1100,max=1300)

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot reproduce your problem. I do in fact get a red line and gray square running your code. Here's what I have: `x <- seq(,1300,length=600); 
y <- dunif(x,min=1100,max=1300);
plot(x,y,type="l",xlim=c(1000,1500),ylim=c(0,0.009),lwd=2,col="red", ylab="p");
polygon(c(1100,x,1300),c(0,y,0),col="lightgray",border=NA)` ... you might want to clear your environment, remove any available plots, restart R...